# Are point-based reward apps haram?

Tags: halal-haram, gambling

Assalamu Alaikum,
So there's this thing called Microsoft Rewards which gives you points for searching things using the Microsoft Bing search engine. You can use those points to redeem for rewards, like gift cards. You can also use the "Give Mode" to have your points be donated to charity. I only use the Give Mode and donate the points that I earn to charity. Is this haram?

Comment: What would make it haram?

Comment: If it is not gambling, then it is not haram. From the way you explained, I don't see anything related to gambling, unless you edit the question and elaborate.